# How to add Azure Functions extension

Tags: azure-functions, precompiled

I'm experimenting with extensions in Azure Functions as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46553687/azure-function-run-code-on-startup) but can't get it to work.

My code looks like this: (pre-compiled, consumption plan)

```
public static class FirstFunction
{
    [FunctionName("FirstFunction"),]
    public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *", RunOnStartup = true)]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info($"Started = { TestExtension.Started }");
        log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    }
}

public class TestExtension : IExtensionConfigProvider
{
    public static bool Started = false;

    public void Initialize(ExtensionConfigContext context) {
        Started = true;
        Console.WriteLine("TestExtensionConsole");
        context.Trace.Error("TestExtension");

        throw new Exception("TextExtensionException");
    }
}
```

But nothing happens at runtime. I see the log from the timer `Started = false` but nothing else.

Do I need to enable extensions or something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Running code on startup is not exactly the purpose of `IExtensionConfigProvider`. It's designed as extensibility point for user to create custom bindings.

So, unless your functions are using custom bindings, the implementations of `IExtensionConfigProvider` won't be auto-loaded by the runtime host, see [code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/blob/7403a31d9161ea7574e1bd945759b9735042127b/src/WebJobs.Script/Host/ScriptHost.cs#L533-L535).

The author of the answer that you are referring to was using his extension to [implement Dependency Injection](https://github.com/BorisWilhelms/azure-function-dependency-injection) with custom bindings, so it works for him.

If you intend to use your extension for custom binding, then use that binding in a function and the extension will start loading.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I plan to use it for DI but first I did a small test.