# Azure - Execute some code before each request to Function app

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-functions

I have created an azure function app and created few functions into it.
I wanted to check if the user is authorized to access the route or not (from my DB).
I need to check this before the request execution.
How can I achieve this in function app?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using function v2 with c#, then you can write your own `Startup class` and register it with your function. The `Startup class` always executes prior to the function executes.

Please also make sure you're using the latest version of `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` nuget package(the latest version is **1.0.29** as of now)

Here is a sample code, and please feel free to modify it as per your need:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.IO;

[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(FunctionApp16.MyStartup))]
namespace FunctionApp16
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run("your parameters")
        {
            //your code here
        }
    }

    public class MyStartup : IWebJobsStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
        {
            //write your code here, it will executes prior to the function method.
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I am using NodeJs .

Comment: @MILJOJOHN, for node.js, I just found this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48815835/azure-function-run-code-on-startup-for-node?answertab=active#tab-top), you can see if it can help or not.

Comment: @MILJOJOHN, can you solve your issue as per the link I provided in comment?

Answer (score 0):

Azure API Management services enables JWT validation on all incoming requests.

> The validate-jwt policy enforces existence and validity of a JWT extracted from either a specified HTTP Header or a specified query parameter.

Among enforcing other security and authorization use cases, this is very useful for checking for permissions in claims. You can read more in the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#ValidateJWT). While this won't query your DB for user permissions, it is a very effective way to achieve your goal.

Here's the syntax from the documentation.

```
  <required-claims>
    <claim name="name of the claim as it appears in the token" match="all|any" separator="separator character in a multi-valued claim">
      <value>claim value as it is expected to appear in the token</value>
      <!-- if there is more than one allowed values, then add additional value elements -->
    </claim>
    <!-- if there are multiple possible allowed values, then add additional value elements -->
  </required-claims>
```

Here's how you could implement it.

```
  <required-claims>
    <claim name="FirstRoute" match="any">
      <value>true</value>
    </claim>
    <claim name="SecondRoute" match="any">
      <value>false</value>
    </claim>
  </required-claims>
```