# IExtensionConfigProvider not initializing or binding with Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs v3

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

We use dependency injection in our Azure Function (v2 on netstandard20) using parameter binding with IExtensionConfigProvider.  After upgrading Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions from 1.0.13 to 1.0.19 (which forced an upgrade of Microsoft.Azure.Webjobs.Host to v3) this doesn't work anymore.  I can't hit a breakpoint in my IExtensionConfigProvider.Initialize function any more.  The same version of the Functions SDK works fine for a sample project with target framework net462, for which it uses Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs v2.

Here's the error it gives at runtime:

> Error indexing method 'Function1.Run'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host:
>   Cannot bind parameter 'customThing' to type CustomType. Make sure the
>   parameter Type is supported by the binding.

And here's the code for the sample app:

```
    public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("ThisFunction")]
    public static async Task Run(
        [TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")]TimerInfo timer,
        [Inject(typeof(CustomType))] CustomType customThing,
        ExecutionContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(customThing.GetMessage());
    }
}

public class CustomType
{
    public string GetMessage() => "Hi";
}

[Binding]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
public class InjectAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Type Type { get; }
    public InjectAttribute(Type type) => Type = type;
}

public class InjectConfiguration : IExtensionConfigProvider
{
    private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public void Initialize(ExtensionConfigContext context)
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddSingleton<CustomType>();
        _serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider(true);

        context
            .AddBindingRule<InjectAttribute>()
            .BindToInput<dynamic>(i => _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(i.Type));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Tom, there's active discussion here on github: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/684#issuecomment-417739149

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With the changes made in v3 to DI and the extension model to create a extension (an **IExtensionConfigProvider** implementation is an extension) now you first need to create a startup class, using **[assembly:WebJobsStartup]** assembly attribute and implementing **IWebJobsStartup** interface. In there you can add your own services to the builder via **builder.Services** and register your extension's config provider class:

```
[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(WebJobsExtensionStartup ), "A Web Jobs Extension Sample")]
namespace ExtensionSample
{
    public class WebJobsExtensionStartup : IWebJobsStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
        {
             //Don't need to create a new service collection just use the built-in one
             builder.Services.AddSingleton<CustomType>();                 

             //Registering an extension
             builder.AddExtension<InjectConfiguration>(); 
        }
    } 
}
```

Then in your **IExtensionConfigProvider** you can inject any dependencies via constructor injections, for example, binding, bindingproviders, or any other custom dependency. In your case you can just get a reference to the built-in **IServiceProvider**:

```
public class InjectConfiguration : IExtensionConfigProvider
{
    private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public InjectConfiguration(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
       _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public void Initialize(ExtensionConfigContext context)
    {         
        context
            .AddBindingRule<InjectAttribute>()
            .BindToInput<dynamic>(i => _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(i.Type));
    }
}
```

To get the host to load the extension, it must be registered inside **bin/extensions.json** file, in JavaScript or Java functions via the func extensions install command. In C# the **SDK 1.0.19** looks at build time for classes attributed with **WebJobsStartup** assembly attribute in the current function project or any dependency (**ProjectReference** or **PackageReference**) of the current project, and generates the corresponding extensions.json file.

Comment: Thanks!  That last paragraph is a little unclear to me - if I add the WebJobsStartup attribute in C#, do I still need to manually create an extensions.json file?

Comment: No,by using the  WebJobsStartup the sdk generates it at build time.

Comment: Man, u save my day!

Comment: For those running into an issue where extensions.json file is empty on the host machine, you can copy your local one over to the host machine via cloud explorer.

Comment: THere is currently an issue wtih creating the correct extensions.json on publish, which does not include the startup class when it is in the function assembly. A workaround for this can be found here https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3386#issuecomment-419565714

Comment: For anyone else wondering, WebJobsStartup and related types can be found in the "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions" NuGet package.