# Initializing AutoMapper in an Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, initialization, automapper, azure-functions

I am trying to create an Azure function in which I am using some code with AutoMapper. I am quite new to C#, Azure and AutoMapper and I'm having some trouble finding the correct way of initializing my AutoMapper configuration.

**MapInitializer.cs:**

```
public static class MapInitializer
    {
        public static void Activate()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                // initialize mappings here
            });
        }
    }
```

Then in my function, I am trying to do the following:

**Function.cs:**

```
public static class ProcessQueueForIntercom
    {

        [FunctionName("ProcessQueue")]
        public static void Run([QueueTrigger("messages")]string myQueueItem, TraceWriter log)
        {
            MapInitializer.Activate(); 

            // rest of the code
        }
    }
```

Now the problem is, the first time I processed a message with this function, everything went smoothly and the code ran as I expected. However, from the second time on, I get an error saying my configuration is already initialized. But I don't really have an idea on how to do this properly with an Azure Function, since normally you would initialize this in the App Startup, but I don't think there is such a thing for Azure Functions (CMIW), and I'm not finding much information about how to exactly do this. I was thinking about just surrounding the Activate() call with a try catch and just log a warning that the configuration is already loaded, but that doesn't seem very clean...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You only need to call `Activate` once. You can do it from a static constructor:

```
public static class ProcessQueueForIntercom
{
    static ProcessQueueForIntercom()
    {
        MapInitializer.Activate();
    }

    [FunctionName("ProcessQueue")]
    public static void Run([QueueTrigger("messages")]string myQueueItem, TraceWriter log)
    {             
        // rest of the code
    }
}
```

Or just make a static constructor on `MapInitializer` itself.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45495337/1171619).

Comment: This works great, thank you! I hadn't seen/used a static constructor before, interesting!

Comment: @Mikhail Thanks for introducing me to  static constructor  :)

Comment: How do you use the mapper that you have initialized in the static consturctor ProcessQueueForIntercom() in your function "ProcessQueue"? How do you get to the "_mapper" instance from your function?

Answer (score 1):

As the static `Mapper.Initialize` API is now officially dead, I think the best solution is to inject a mapper in the function class constructor. So, assuming you want to map `User` model to `UserResponse` DTO, you need to first configure an automapper in your `Startup.cs` like this

```
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using YourNamespace.Models;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(YourNamespace.Startup))]

namespace YourNamespace
{
    class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            var mappperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
                {
                cfg.CreateMap<User, UserResponse>(); 
                // you can have the maps in a dedicated Profile subclass if you like
            });
            builder.Services.AddSingleton(mappperConfig.CreateMapper());
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you inject the automapper to your functions class like this:

```
public class UsersApi
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public UsersApi(IMapper mapper)
    {
        _mapper = mapper; 
    }

    [FunctionName(nameof(UsersApi.GetUser))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetUser(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "users/{id}")] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log,
        string id)
    {
        User user = await UserRepository.GetUser(id);
        UserResponse res = _mapper.Map<UserResponse>(user);
        return new OkObjectResult(res);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that constructor is called for every invocation. If that's the case, it's an anti pattern, the config should be singleton.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Thank you for reviewing my answer. Why exactly is it an anti-pattern? Does the automapper documentation say something about it? Also, what should be implemented as singleton? The config or the mapper itself? Or both?

Comment: The config, https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Getting-started.html#where-do-i-configure-automapper

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu thanks again. So apparently there's no better way than using DI... I'll rewrite my answer.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core