# Do Azure Functions have "start up" lifecycle methods?

Tags: azure-functions

Within ASP.NET MVC applications there is the `Application_Start` method within `Global.asax.cs` where you can bootstrap things such as dependency injection registration. Is there such a thing for Azure Functions?

I'm aware of the `IExtensionConfigProvider` interface and the `Initialise` method when you're using bindings but I'm not using them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No specific method for this. The idea is tracked in [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/586).

One option for now is to use a static constructor, see examples in similar questions [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47551229/1171619) and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45495337/1171619).